# How to configure phonegap for android

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap

I have set up both the desktop application and installed the PhoneGap developer app on my phone. Opening the Hello World demo works on my phone. The issue is when I try to run the jquery mobile website I built for the purpose of turning it into apps for IOS and android through PhoneGap.  Trying to run the website through PhoneGap on my phone results in this error:

> net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(file:///data/user/0/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/phonegapdevapp/www/login.html)

As a website, the index page will redirect the user to the login page if you aren't logged in.

```
function ExistingUser(){
    //alert(localStorage.getItem("token"));
    var returnValue = 3;
    if (localStorage.getItem("token")){
        //code that calls a web service

    }else{
        window.location = "login.html";

    }
}
```

In response to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496411/cordova-err-file-not-foundfile-android-assets-www-index-html), I've added an AndroidManifest.xml file to platforms/android/ folder, though I'm not super confident that the attributes are adequate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest>
    <uses-permission />
    <!-- Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <permission />
    <permission-tree />
    <permission-group />
    <instrumentation />
    <uses-sdk />
    <uses-configuration />  
    <uses-feature />  
    <supports-screens />  
    <compatible-screens />  
    <supports-gl-texture />  

    <application>

        <activity>
            <intent-filter>
                <action />
                <category />
                <data />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </activity>

        <activity-alias>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </activity-alias>

        <service>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data/>
        </service>

        <receiver>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </receiver>

        <provider>
            <grant-uri-permission />
            <meta-data />
            <path-permission />
        </provider>

        <uses-library />

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that PhoneGap treats files names as case sensitive. In a web browser `window.location = "login.html";` loads the Login.html page.